# FaceTracking in ARKit – How to display the "lookAtPoint" on the screen

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, eye-tracking

The `ARFaceTrackingConfiguration` of ARKit places `ARFaceAnchor` with information about the position and orientation of the face onto the scene. Among others, this anchor has the `lookAtPoint` property that I'm interested in. I know that this vector is relative to the face. How can I draw a point on the screen for this position, meaning how can I translate this point's coordinates?

Comment: The approach of using `leftEyeTransform` and `rightEyeTransform` instead of `lookAtPoint` is also highly appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

#### `.lookAtPoint` property is for direction's estimation only

Apple documentation says: `.lookAtPoint` is a position in face coordinate space that is estimating only the gaze of face's direction. It's a vector of three scalar values, and it's just gettable, not settable:

```
var lookAtPoint: SIMD3<Float> { get }
```

In other words, this is the resulting vector from the product of two quantities – `.rightEyeTransform` and `.leftEyeTransform` instance properties (which also are just gettable):

```
var rightEyeTransform: simd_float4x4 { get }
var leftEyeTransform: simd_float4x4 { get }
```

Here's an imaginary situation on how you could use this instance property:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        
    if let faceAnchor = anchor as? ARFaceAnchor,
       let faceGeometry = node.geometry as? ARSCNFaceGeometry {
            
        if (faceAnchor.lookAtPoint.x >= 0) {         // Looking (+X)
            faceGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "redTexture.png")
        } else {                                     // Looking (-X)
            faceGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "cyanTexture.png")
        }

        faceGeometry.update(from: faceAnchor.geometry)
        facialExrpession(anchor: faceAnchor)
            
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.label.text = self.textBoard
        }
    }
}
```

And here's an image showing axis directions for ARFaceTrackingConfiguration():

[image]

#### Answering your question

I could say that you can't manage this point's coordinates directly because it's gettable-only property (and there is just XYZ orientation, not XYZ translation).

So if you need both – translation and rotation – use `.rightEyeTransform` and `.lefttEyeTransform` instance properties instead.

---

---

##### Projecting a point

There are two methods for point projection in `SceneKit`/`ARKit`. Use the following instance [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1524089-projectpoint) for projecting a point onto 2D view (for `sceneView` instance):

```
func projectPoint(_ point: SCNVector3) -> SCNVector3
```

or:

```
let sceneView = ARSCNView()
sceneView.projectPoint(myPoint)
```

Also, in `ARKit` you have to implement the following instance [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2923538-projectpoint) for projecting a point onto 2D view (for `arCamera` instance):

```
func projectPoint(_ point: simd_float3, 
              orientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, 
             viewportSize: CGSize) -> CGPoint
```

or:

```
let camera = ARCamera()
camera.projectPoint(myPoint, orientation: myOrientation, viewportSize: vpSize)
```

This method helps you project a point from the 3D world coordinate system of the scene to the 2D pixel coordinate system of the renderer.

---

---

##### Unrojecting a point

There's also the SceneKit's [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522631-unprojectpoint) for unprojecting a point:

```
func unprojectPoint(_ point: SCNVector3) -> SCNVector3
```

For more details read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76475229/how-to-render-spheres-in-scenekit-at-users-tap-position/76478828#76478828).

...and ARKit's [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/3003663-unprojectpoint) for unprojecting a point:

```
@nonobjc func unprojectPoint(_ point: CGPoint, 
            ontoPlane planeTransform: simd_float4x4, 
                         orientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, 
                        viewportSize: CGSize) -> simd_float3?
```