# ARRaycastQuery and Front Facing Camera (ARFaceTrackingConfiguration)

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I've searched all over the docs and might simply be missing something very big. Is raycasting available on front-facing True Depth cameras like on the iPad Pro?

I'm working on an application currently where I'm in ARFaceTrackingConfiguration and a simple raycast from the screen center is not yielding results.

That same code in World configuration using the rear camera is producing results. This code is straight from the docs.

```
let raycastQuery: ARRaycastQuery? = sceneView.raycastQuery(
                                                      from: sceneView.center,
                                                  allowing: .estimatedPlane,
                                                 alignment: .any)

let rayresults: [ARRaycastResult] = sceneView.session.raycast(raycastQuery!)
print(rayresults)
```

My understanding, given the examples around face tracking depth maps for background blur, was that the front camera would have essentially the same depth data as the rear, just with less total depth distance available.

Since this code returns a result set on the Rear Camera but does not return results on the Front Camera, I'm wondering if it is because of the direction of the ray? For the Front Camera, if rayCast is supported, maybe it requires the ray to be cast in the negative z direction? But I haven't had success there.

The goal of the project is to be able to get the distance between 2 points in 3D space but with the front camera not the rear.

Thanks for setting me straight! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Hit-testing for ARFaceTrackingConfig

It's obvious that the ARKit raycasting methods used for detected planes based on World Tracking config will not work for the Face Tracking scenario. In your case, you need to use SceneKit's hit-testing. For hit-testing you will not be able to use `estimatedPlane`, you'll need a `canonical face mask`. And you are absolutely right about the XZ coordinates when using the front camera - the XZ plane is [mirrored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55066870/facetracking-in-arkit-how-to-display-the-lookatpoint-on-the-screen/58146090#58146090). It is also worth noting that the camera's IR TrueDepth sensor "works" at a distance from 10 to 100 cm. ARFaceAnchor is generated only within this range.

Run this code on your iPad Pro in the Swift Playgrounds app.

```
import ARKit
import SceneKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController : UIViewController {
    var sceneView = ARSCNView(frame: .zero)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view = self.sceneView
        sceneView.delegate = self
        sceneView.scene = SCNScene()
        
        let config = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
        config.maximumNumberOfTrackedFaces = 1
        sceneView.session.run(config)
    }
}
```

---

```
extension ViewController {       
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let location: CGPoint? = touches.first?.location(in: sceneView)
                                            
        var hitTestOptions = [SCNHitTestOption: Any]()
        hitTestOptions[.boundingBoxOnly] = true
                                            
        let hitTestResults: [SCNHitTestResult] = sceneView.hitTest(location!, 
                                                   options: hitTestOptions)
                    
        guard let hit = hitTestResults.first else { return }
                                        
        let sphere = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 0.005))
        sphere.simdPosition = hit.simdWorldCoordinates
        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphere)            
    }
}
```

---

```
extension ViewController : ARSCNViewDelegate {
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
        let faceGeo = ARSCNFaceGeometry(device: sceneView.device!)
        let node = SCNNode(geometry: faceGeo)
        node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = .physicallyBased
        node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green
        return node
    }
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode,
                                                    for anchor: ARAnchor) {    
        if let faceAnchor = anchor as? ARFaceAnchor,
           let faceGeo = node.geometry as? ARSCNFaceGeometry {
            faceGeo.update(from: faceAnchor.geometry)
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

Comment: Brilliant, Andy. As usual. Thank you for the detail, and so quickly. I had overlooked completely the SceneKit hit testing. But I suppose this leads me to another conclusion and that is that since we can’t use .estimatedPlane, and it must be geometry, that I can’t really search for non-face anchors then? Am I correct in that thinking? The front camera doesn’t allow us to raycast in the same way, so if I wanted to find the 3D depth pixel location of a non face anchor I’d have to use an entirely different method than Ray or hit testing? If it’s even possible at all.

Comment: ARFaceTrackingConfig is self-explanatory - it was created for face tracking only with the corresponding tools (such as blendshapes and canonical face mesh). There is neither planes and images detection nor raycasting & scene reconstruction options for this type of config. In fact, face tracking is the only AR config that uses a [front camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61045268/arkit-how-to-use-arimagetrackingconfiguration-with-arfacetrackingconfiguration/61060025#61060025).
If you want to use the tools available in ARWorldTrackingConfig, then why don't you use the back camera?

Comment: I totally agree that it seems like I’m being a bit dense in my understanding, I apologize for that. The use case I’m exploring uses the front camera but not for face tracking, I want to measure 2 points in 3D space but I’d prefer the Front Camera to the back. The reason I keep asking silly questions is I was hoping to leverage the similar features of the front camera (depth mainly) and using it in Face Tracking is the only way to get the front. You have pointed me in the right direction though thank you! I should be looking at depth data I think with AVFoundation

Comment: @K_C, it's ok. I would like to add a few words to the above, about the max working distance of ARFaceAnchor. The IR emitter projects 30K dots onto the user's face. When the distance is more than 1 meter from the gadget to the face, the IR camera is not able to capture a high-quality depth channel (the projected dots become too big and blurry), so the ARFaceTracking experience will be destroyed.

Comment: Thank you, Andy. I wish Apple’s docs had some of this info you’ve shared, it’s really helpful.